# employer changed the boss to whom I report on my first day

Tags: professionalism, work-environment, hiring-process

It was my first day at a new job and I met with the hiring manager (HM), also the person to whom I would report according to the offer letter. HM then told me that I need to report to another person, who is at a much lower rank.  I am very disappointed and unhappy about the situation.

Is this type of change common?  What is the professional way to deal with this situation?

I was thinking of writing to the HM expressing my disappointment and surprise and explaining to him that being able to report to her directly is an important reason I quit my previous job and took this job.  And I also wanted to ask him to reconsider the change.  Meanwhile, I think I will have to be on the job market again because I am not sure whether I should trust this company anymore.

Anything else I could do?

Comment: Related question: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/66814/is-it-okay-to-be-moved-under-a-different-manager-without-your-consent

Comment: Why does your manager's designation matter to you? For God's sake, don't say anything about your manager's rank being lower than your "expected" manager rank. The future you will thank you for it. It would be much worse if you do it in writing, you would come across as extremely immature if you do that.

Answer (score 7):

We can't tell you what to do, however here's some advice:

> ***Sending that letter is incredibly silly.***

There was another word starting with "s" that I wanted to use there, but I've refrained.

It's safe to say that this manager has a list of responsibilities which is much longer than yours. Delegation of responsibilities is a key skill to master, and managers who operate in a very hands-on, micro-managerial sort of way are not typically the ones who go on to bigger and better things.

He hired you to do a job, not to speak to you on a daily, or even weekly basis. And he has deemed your input not to be worthy of his time on a regular basis. This might not be pleasant to hear, however here's a reality check:

> He's the one who knows how the organization runs. He's the one who knows best how to distribute the workload, and who to trust. You're the new guy. What the heck do you know about his schedule?

Do a good job and maybe one day soon he'll want to listen to your input personally. But if you keep behaving like a spoiled brat then you most likely the next time you will speak to him personally will be when he fires you - and for good reason.

Comment: I think this is a great answer until the last sentence - there's no need for the "spoiled brat" assumption. Someone may show up that isn't thinking of writing a letter and wants to know how to approach it instead. I know I would be *disappointed* if the manager I decided to work for was changed - even if they left of their own accord.

Comment: @Raystafarian - I understand your point. I would be dissapointed as well. I might even be bitter, or decide that I don't want to work there anymore. However writing a letter admonishing my boss about it? ***Especially*** as the new guy on the team? That's why I feel that the OP is coming across as a bit of an entitled brat.

Comment: Fair enough, it is your answer and I think it's good without it, still +1 from me.

Answer (score 4):

As I wrote [as an answer to a previous question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/66821/3), changed in the management hierarchy are common for a number of reasons. As organizations change, managers also change. There may be layers of management added and/or removed to balance the workload and who reports to various managers would change based on the employees, managers, and projects. Unless you're part of the organization leadership, there shouldn't be an expectation on your part to be informed of or need to agree to changes in the leadership structure above you.

Taking a job because of who you report to is a very risky proposition, as you've found out. Even taking a job because you want to work with specific individuals is risky, since individuals move. You may choose to work in a company because they do certain work and have or attract experts in a particular field that you are interested in working in or learning more about, but trying your work to people and expecting that to be unchanging isn't necessarily the best thing that you can do for your career development.

Writing a letter to your hiring manager because you are disappointed in the organization will only make you seem extremely difficult to work with. Effectively, you are saying that you are disappointed in business decisions because you took a huge risk and lost.

Unless something about your position, such as your role, responsibilities, salary, or title, changed, you shouldn't go complaining to the hiring manager, or anyone else. You still do have the opportunity to work in the same organization as the person that you wanted to. After you get settled in, you can ask about a mentorship relationship with the original person, to learn from them.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the needs of the company or the team changed between the moment they interviewed you and your first day of work.

If your salary does not change, and the tasks for which you've been hired are not different from the job description, you should really bite the bullet and do your job.

Don't bring this up as it will serve absolutely no purpose and make you look like you're whining.

The HM has job to do, and is able to delegate management of other employees to his own staff. I don't see what is wrong with that.

Maybe you could bring this up *later* when you've been working there for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Job interviews work as a two way assessment as does probationary period.

You obviously feel they dealt with you disingenuously during the interview process in that the shape of the job is quite different from what you have been led to believe.  As others have stated this is fairly common in that workplace structure changes over time, often without input of those affected.

My opinion differs from the others in that if the present situation is completely unacceptable and you are going to leave if it doesn't change, you should say something.  They went through the cost and effort to hire you, if this is a total deal breaker they may adjust for you.  Saying something gives them the chance to address a problem that they would otherwise not know exists.  You risk coming off as entitled but a deal breaker is a deal breaker.  If they can't accommodate you with an acceptable employment situation use your probationary period.

Tone will be very important in how you address this.  Meet the HM face to face.  Go through specifically what was said during the interview and in the offer letter that has changed.  Say that these points were selling features for accepting this offer then listen to their response.